# How to write generic type for literal name in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I am writing `d.ts` file for `js-data` library, and the following code can simplify my demands:

```js
interface Note {
  id: number,
  title: string,
  text: string
}
interface Comment {
  id: number,
  content: string,
  noteId: number
}

function create(name: 'note', attrs: Note): Note
function create(name: 'comment', attrs: Comment): Comment
// ... and so on
```

Based on above definitions, I can invoke functions for type checks:

```js
create('note', { id: 1, title: 'note title', body: 'note body' }) // work
create('comment', { id: 11, content: 'comment content', noteId: 1 }) // work

create('nott', ...) // not work, there is a spelling mistake
create('note', { id: 11, content: 'comment content', noteId: 1 }) // not work, attrs should be type Note
```

Though I can write as many as possible overloading functions like above, but the work is too tedious. Is there any way to simplify such work with generics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type Attrs = {
  note: Note
  comment: Comment
}

type AttrName = keyof Attrs

declare function create<T extends AttrName>(name: T, attrs: Attrs[T]): Note
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAXaKkG8BQ2lIEtg0AnAMwWQDkB7NLPfQgEwC4lgBXMAIwhIA0jfCgIoANhHZQUJIgHMhTVBAAeKabIWMAvo0ZFSFREgDCNMJGINlBNh259BwpPBrEIxTXOCKXwOggASXsuXn5dXBEATxhkAEEUWSgkAF4bJgC0dlo0FzdLTw0zCysUSMYUWISkkipwZHSAawhomjIkROSopGYIeHEQEmQyTmB4UXdXYZA0AB4AFSQ1NGBmFK66hoA+AApQSHYFgSRZ5PZNqABtBYBdAEocwJ74GbRdgHIsiA+TzBZ2ABGE6iCRSJBfQKoMSSX4qdTsSH0Hg0ZjRD5IHT3JAAehxSAA7jQSE1GK8ILMIJ8CmU4f87EDga53Ktih8aUVmR5iHDviEgZjsXjCcTSWS3lSkSg6VjcfisiKSSCABb8ZAEFIgJCwCDicQKJBgDUoEAtcUU95In5-AFIQFMtzctkc6yO1m8wL8u2CuUcOiKponM4kFJQZU0TjiZhIPioapIXIQXA6IA)